# Saving points to file Java

Tags: java

I honestly could not find any post that could answer my question which is, If I had ~4 games which require the user to enter a bet and if they won, how would I save that new money amount to file every time? So, if I had a lot of if statements such as a dice game

```
 if (UserPlay.equals(ComputerPlay))
    {
        System.out.print("Tie");
    }
    else if (UserPlay == "Rock" && ComputerPlay == "Paper" )
    {
        System.out.print("Computer wins");
        money = money - (bet * 2);
    }
    else if (UserPlay == "Rock" && ComputerPlay == "Scissors")
    {
        System.out.print("You win");
        money = money + (bet * 2);
    }
    .... etc
```

How would I keep updating my file to overwrite the previous money amount in order so that if the user exits and enters the game again, the money amount would stay the same.

Comment: Do you know how to [read and write files in Java](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/io/)?  If not, read the tutorial(s).

Comment: I know how to read and write files in, i'm not sure about how to overwite a file. I'll go read a tutorial just in case. Thanks

Comment: If you write to a file with a `FileOutputStream` or something similar it should overwrite your file automatically

Answer (score 1):

Try to use `equals` method instead of `==` like this:

```
  else if ("Rock".equals(UserPlay) && "Paper".equals(ComputerPlay))
  ...
  else if ("Rock".equals(UserPlay) && "Scissors".equals(ComputerPlay))
  ...
```

More details to understand [Equals Vs ==](http://cosenonjaviste.it/tutorial-java-il-metodo-equals-e-loperatore/)

Answer (score 0):

For your data to save it in the file and read it again, you can try this:

```
// when write
OutputStream out = new FileOutputStream(new File("data.txt"));
out.write(String.valueOf(money).getBytes());
out.close();

try {
    // and when read, it is better to put it in the try catch block
    // maybe for the first time cannot find the file
    InputStream in = new FileInputStream(new File("data.txt"));
    byte[] b = new byte[1024];
    in.read(b);
    in.close();
    money = Integer.parseInt(new String(b));
} catch (IOException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
}
```

Comment: Thanks, ill try this now and come back.

Answer (score 0):

You can create a file to hold all info in pairs player-money, and read/rewrite if needs. If player logged in again - you just need to find him in file, and read money value.

Answer (score 0):

1. You cannot compare strings with "==" operator, because it's comparision for object links. Use [.equals()](http://alvinalexander.com/java/edu/qanda/pjqa00001.shtml) method:

```
String name1 = "John"
String name2 = "Gregor"

if (name.equals(some)) {
   // ...
}
```

2. Try Java [Properties](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Properties.html) as your storage engine

records will look like:

```
John=352  
Stella=363  
Henry=543
```